# Multihilos o Procesos Python

Tags: python, hilos

estoy intentando descargar informacion de una api, el problema es que la api solo da 1 dato por link... y necesito descargar cerca de 10 millon de datos.

```
import multiprocessing
import urllib.request
import json
import mysql.connector


def worker():
    """worker function"""
    x = 10

    for i in range (1000):
        try:
            x = x + 1
    
            url = 'https://example.com/user.aspx?type=96&nroReg='+str(x)+'&sex=M'
            req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    
            r = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
            cont = json.loads(r.decode("utf-8"))
    
            print(cont['user']["denominacion"])
 
     
     
    conexion1=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
     
     
     
            conexion1=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",  
                     user="root",
                 user="root",  
                            passwd="",
          passwd="", 
                                      database="api_download")
            cursor1=conexion1.cursor()
            sql="insert into usu(denominacion,nroReg) values (%s,%s)"
            datos=(cont['user']["denominacion"], cont['user']["nroReg"])
            cursor1.execute(sql, datos)
            conexion1.commit()
            conexion1.close()
        except KeyError: 
                    print('Error Folder')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

actualmente tengo ese código, procesa rapido, pero el problema es que tambien me repite varias veces la misma funcion... por ejemplo donde dice x=10 se supone que va a correr el programa 10 veces, y lo hace... pero yo debo entrar al 10... 11... 12 etc pero aqui me ingresa 10 veces al 10... 10 veces al 11 etc...

donde esta la falla? si hago sin el threading tarda aproximadamente 1 segundo por cada y teniendo en cuenta que tengo que descargar mas de 10 millon, me llevaria meses

Comment: El problema es que a cada hilo le pasas el mismo método, todos con la variable `x = 10`, con lo cual todos empiezan por el mismo sitio... Podrías usar una cola (Queue) y se la pasas al worker. Entonces usas un thread para ir "generando" trabajos en la cola y los demás para ir consumiéndolos. De esa manera nunca se repetirán. De todas maneras, si la api que atacas es tuya, te recomiendo que hagas un endpoint donde puedes descargar en grupo... hacer ***10 millones de llamadas*** a una api va a llevarle MUCHO tiempo, uses hilos o no

Comment: Es probable que el servidor en cuestión imponga algún límite en la cantidad de conexiones desde una misma IP, o la cantidad de clientes activos en total. También es probable que a nivel de sistema operativo haya alguna regla que limite el número de sesiones TCP/IP que se pueden abrir desde una IP dada (para evitar ataques de denegación de servicio). Sería útil revisar primero cuantas conexiones en paralelo puedes hacer.

Comment: Hola, muchisimas gracias, ahi con el ejemplo de mas abajo pude optimizar al doble casi el tiempo... en cuanto a la api no tiene ningun limite ni bloqueo, básicamente estoy haciendo una migración de un sistema totalmente arruinado al nuevo y como hay que mover muchos datos de lugar en diferentes tablas hice el script, vale aclarar igualmente estoy dentro de la red el dominio es un ejemplo, hago el "ataque" desde la red... tampoco tienen accceso a la base de datos para salvar los datos, estas cosas pasan cuando despiden al administrador de sistemas y no guardan las claves de las cosas jaja

Answer (score 0):

Es que en todas estas llamando a la misma función, el programa no sabe que quieres sacar de 1000 en adelante con la siguiente iteración.

Lo que puedes hacer es usar un parámetro y enviarlo cada que pases por la iteración

```
def worker(start=0):
    x = 10 + start
    ...
for i in range(5):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i*1000,))
    ...
```

Así, al multiplicar `i*1000`, en la primera le mandas 0 (x=10), luego 1000 (x=1010), 2000 (x=2010), etc.

Como adicional y posible duda, la tupla `args=(i*1000,)` tiene que tener una coma al final, porque como es de un solo elemento, Python no sabe si es solo una variable entre paréntesis, que no queremos, o una tupla. Con la coma, lo hacemos explícito.

También, ten cuidado con cuántos hilos uses, muchas APIs tienen un límite de cuántas llamadas puedes hacer por segundo.

Comment: entonces quedaria: 

`import multiprocessing
import urllib.request
import json
import mysql.connector


def worker(start=0):
    x = 10203303 + start

    for i in range (1000):
        try:
            x = x + 1
    
            url =.....'`

y abajo 
`
if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(50):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i*1000,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()`

o me equivoco? porque asi veo que anda un poco mas rapido pero no veo diferencia en que haga varios al mismo tiempo

Comment: Claro. la verdad, lo vi desde un punto de vista enteramente de "que funcione". No conozco muy bien `multiprocessing`, así que no te podré ayudar con el resto. A lo mejor puedes usar `threading` en su lugar, pero como te digo, no soy muy conocedor.